# Error while importing tensorflow after installing successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying out tensorflow on my Mac. I use python 3.7 in a virtual environment.
I installed TensorFlow using `pip install tensorflow` successfully.

But now when I try to import it `import tensorflow`, it gives the following error

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 959, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements')
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing import stringStart, stringEnd, originalTextFor, ParseException
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/extern/__init__.py", line 43, in load_module
    __import__(extant)
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 4756, in <module>
    _escapedPunc = Word( _bslash, r"\[]-*.$+^?()~ ", exact=2 ).setParseAction(lambda s,l,t:t[0][1])
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1284, in setParseAction
    self.parseAction = list(map(_trim_arity, list(fns)))
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1066, in _trim_arity
    this_line = extract_stack(limit=2)[-1]
  File "/Users/sourabh/virtualenvs/ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/pyparsing.py", line 1050, in extract_stack
    frame_summary = traceback.extract_stack(limit=-offset+limit-1)[offset]
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 211, in extract_stack
    stack = StackSummary.extract(walk_stack(f), limit=limit)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 363, in extract
    f.line
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 285, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 48, in getlines
    for mod in sys.modules.values():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Comment: Have you seen this open issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33183 ? Maybe it can help you!
Are you also running Catalina?

Comment: Yes, I recently updated to Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the exact same problem, according https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33183 this is an os-x catalina issue. However I found you can simply use python 3.7.6 to get rid of the problem, i.e. os-x catalina's python3 is version 3.7.3, with brew you can install python 3.7.6, backwards compatible and solves the problem :)